# angular - how to combine few ngclass together in one div

Tags: typescript, angular9, ng-class, angularjs-ng-class, angular-ng-class

I would like to combine multiple ngClass if else statement together,  I have tried but not able to resolve it.

```
<div
    [ngClass]="[tabItem === 'unavailable' ? 'background-grey' : selected ? 'card-selected cursor' : 'cursor']"
    [ngClass]="[hasAlerts ? 'banner' : 'no-banner']">
</div>
```

My attempt:

```
<div
    [ngClass]="[{'banner': hasAlerts, 'no-banner': !hasAlerts}, tabItem === 'unavailable' ? 'background-grey' : selected ? 'card-selected cursor' : 'cursor']">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm finally able to resolve the issue by using this method

```
<div
[ngClass]="{'banner': !!alerts?.length, 'no-banner' : !alerts?.length, 'background-grey': tabItem === 'unavailable', 'cursor': tabItem === 'available', 'card-selected': selected}"
></div>
```